# PySpark Kafka - NoClassDefFound: org/apache/commons/pool2

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-kafka-integration

I am encountering problem with printing the data to console from kafka topic.
The error message I get is shown in below image.
[image: Exception in Task error]

As you can see in the above image that after batch 0 , it doesn't process further.

[image: Error2]

[image: Error3]

All this are snapshots of the error messages. I don't understand the root cause of the errors occurring. Please help me.

Following are kafka and spark version:

```
spark version: spark-3.1.1-bin-hadoop2.7
kafka version: kafka_2.13-2.7.0
```

I am using the following jars:

```
kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar 
spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar 
spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar
```

Here is my code:

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Pyspark structured streaming with kafka and cassandra") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.jars","file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.0-s_2.11.jar,file:///D://mysql-connector-java-5.1.46//mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar")\
        .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath","file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.0-s_2.11.jar,file:///D://mysql-connector-java-5.1.46//mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar")\
        .config("spark.executor.extraLibrary","file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.0-s_2.11.jar,file:///D://mysql-connector-java-5.1.46//mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar")\
        .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath","file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//kafka-clients-2.7.0.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-cassandra-connector-2.4.0-s_2.11.jar,file:///D://mysql-connector-java-5.1.46//mysql-connector-java-5.1.46.jar,file:///C://Users//shivani//Desktop//Spark//spark-token-provider-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.1.jar")\
        .getOrCreate()
    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")


#streaming dataframe that reads from kafka topic
    df_kafka=spark.readStream\
    .format("kafka")\
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",kafka_bootstrap_servers)\
    .option("subscribe",kafka_topic_name)\
    .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
    .load()

    print("Printing schema of df_kafka:")
    df_kafka.printSchema()

    #converting data from kafka broker to string type
    df_kafka_string=df_kafka.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as value")

    # schema to read json format data
    ts_schema = StructType() \
        .add("id_str", StringType()) \
        .add("created_at", StringType()) \
        .add("text", StringType())

    #parse json data
    df_kafka_string_parsed=df_kafka_string.select(from_json(col("value"),ts_schema).alias("twts"))

    df_kafka_string_parsed_format=df_kafka_string_parsed.select("twts.*")
    df_kafka_string_parsed_format.printSchema()


    df=df_kafka_string_parsed_format.writeStream \
    .trigger(processingTime="1 seconds") \
    .outputMode("update")\
    .option("truncate","false")\
    .format("console")\
    .start()

    df.awaitTermination()
```

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: @AchyutVyas I have edited my question and provided the code. Please check out.

Comment: What happens if you remove `kafka-clients` JAR? Also, Windows uses double-backslash for filepaths, not `//` (forward slash does not need "escaped")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error (`NoClassDefFound`, followed by the `kafka010` package) is saying that `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` is missing its transitive dependency on `org.apache.commons:commons-pool2:2.6.2`, as you can [see here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.1.1)

You can either download that JAR as well, or you can change your code to use `--packages` instead of `spark.jars` option, and let Ivy handle downloading transitive dependencies

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache...'

spark = SparkSession.bulider...
```

Comment: Could you expand a bit on this?   I added the .jar via sparkSesh = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/home/ubuntu/jars/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.1.2.jar,/home/ubuntu/jars/commons-pool2-2.11.0.jar") - what's the --packages alternative?

Comment: @James Rather than downloading the JAR, use the Maven coordinates (in the colon separated format) https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12/3.1.2